# Joining 2 sql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

SOLVED: Seems like my server was having issues and was not letting me properly ftp my files. So this whole time my code was correct :/ Just wasted hours of my time! THANKS GO DADDY!

I want to be able to join these two tables on the market_name of table_cars and name of table_price.
I want to pull color and market_name of table_cars, and lowest_price and highest_price of table_price.
But i only want cars with the market_name like 3 series. Can anyone tell me how to select this?

```
table_cars
ID     market_name         color             volume
-----------------------------------------------------
 1      BMW M3             alpine white      2
 2      BMW 3 series       blue              4
 3      BMW 4 series       black             4



table_price
ID      name             lowest_price  highest_price   sale_price
--------------------------------------------------------------------
 1      BMW M3           55000         65000         50000
 2      BMW 3 series     35000         42000         30000
 3      BMW 4 series     40000         47000         35000
```

I have tried the query below but does not seem to be working.

```
$sql = "SELECT 
table_cars.market_name, 
table_cars.color, 
table_price.lowest_price,
table_price.highest_price
FROM table_cars INNER JOIN table_price 
ON table_cars.market_name=table_price.name 
WHERE market_name LIKE '%3 series%'";
```

When I echo out the results, nothing appears. Not even "0 results".

```
$result = $connect->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo
        "<div class='col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12'>
          <div class='x_panel tile fixed_height_panel'>
            <div class='x_title name'>
            <h2>" . $row["color"]. "  " . $row["market_name"]. "</h2><br/>
            " . $row["lowest_price"]. " - " . $row["highest_price"]. "
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Comment: `market_hash_name`? You didn't mention this column.

Comment: You shouldn't replicate a non-primary key column in another table to indicate relationship. It could lead to update anomalies.

Comment: sorry, i meant market_name in my original post. Edited!

Comment: Also, if you provided with a more exact reason of why/how it is not working, that would help us a lot.

Comment: are you getting any error while running above query?

Comment: One of the possibilities : invisible space. May be you need to `TRIM` before joining.

Comment: I updated my post and pasted my echo statement.

Comment: Actually those echo statements are not necessary. Better share an **sql fiddle** with the above data.

Comment: *"nothing appears"* - Not even `echo "0 results";` ? Question's a bit unclear in regards to, if you did make a successful connection using the same `mysqli_` API as the query. Check for errors if there are any. Visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php then apply that to your code.

Comment: *"When I echo out the results, nothing appears. Not even "0 results"."* - Your query may have failed you then; again... check for errors and see my comment above also, or it's not even making it there. Curious as to how you're accessing this as though: `http://localhost/file.php` or `file:///file.php`? Two different animals here. @Alex This comment has been edited.

Comment: Yes nothing appears, not even "0 results" It seems like that section of code gets skipped but the rest of my php renders normally. http://localhost/file.php @Fred-ii-  It just might be something else that's not code related happening to my server.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the the string is not exactly `3 series` so try

```
$sql = "SELECT 
table_cars.market_name, 
table_cars.color, 
table_price.lowest_price,
table_price.highest_price
FROM table_cars INNER JOIN table_price 
ON table_cars.market_name=table_price.name 
WHERE market_name LIKE '%3%'
AND market_name LIKE '%series%'
";
```